# Following IHP guide seeing: Web/Controller: getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: does not exist

Tags: ihp

This is all that I see on the loaded page at localhost:8001 after running ./start after following the Hello World instructions on https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/installation.html:

```
Web/Controller: getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: does not exist (No such file or directory)
An exception was raised while running the action TablesAction
```

Has anyone come across this error before? I assume it's an error in the installation process rather than the project.

If it helps diagnose, installation took a *long* time. One section that warned it would take up to 30s took about ten minutes. It seemed unusual.

OS is Mac OS High Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long build time issue is sometimes related to not using the IHP cachix repo:

```
cachix use digitallyinduced
```

For the exception. Do you have other system versions of haskell installed?
The troubleshooting page of the IHP documentation may be of use. You can try to make sure your system is loading .envrc file correctly. If you enter:

```
nix-shell --run 'make build/ihp-lib'
```

That may give a bit more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I get `blog nix-shell --run 'make build/ihp-lib'

mkdir -p build
rm -f build/ihp-lib
ln -s /nix/store/fa3ds971kmcr5hp2i216ahylnc1cvlbx-ghc-8.8.3-with-packages/bin/../lib/IHP build/ihp-lib` for running nix-shell and `cachix use digitallyinduced` looks like it works/has worked, but I get the same error. I don't have another version of haskell installed on this system. I will try reinstalling again from scratch now that I have run these commands.

Comment: - error still present unfortunately. Thanks for the advice though, I'm sure it will help someone so upvoted.

Comment: Cheers. You can also try and start the DevMode with higher verbosity. `DEBUG=1 ./start` this output may be useful.

Comment: It's now working so if anyone is still having difficulty on Mac OS, a simple restart of your Mac might help after following the steps above.